# can a lambda be inherent to a class

Tags: c++

Would it be possible for a lambda, which is inside a class X and defined outside that class X to magically use member variables of that class X ?

Like so:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    std::function<void(void)> f;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;

    foo.x = 10;
    foo.f = []() {
        std::cout << x;
    };

    foo.f();
}
```

It would magically, without any context, use the "x" from the Foo struct.

I thought that because of a lambda being an anonymous struct, if I pass the object "foo" (the C way) in that function, it works, obviously:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    std::function<void(Foo&)> f;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;

    foo.x = 10;
    foo.f = [](Foo& me) {
        std::cout << me.x;
    };

    foo.f(foo);
}
```

Is there any workaround to this ?

Comment: By capture ? `[&foo](){std::cout << foo.x;}` ?

Comment: _"to magically use "_ [The colour of magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwmLgjw3lGs)

Comment: Reaper Man is where he started picking up speed for me.

Comment: "always kings": I don't know why the video is blocked in France, anyways, what the heck did I just watch ? @Jarod42 I didn't think about this.. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural approach would be to use a constructor:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() : f([this](){ std::cout << x; }) {}

    int x;
    std::function<void()> f;
};
```

Or perhaps a default member initializer:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    std::function<void()> f = [this]() { std::cout << x; };
};
```

(The function doesn't take any arguments, of course, so I changed the type of `Foo::f` accordingly.)

The lambda cannot be "inherent to a class", since the lambda refers to an *object* of the class type, so every object must get its own lambda.

Usage:

```
Foo m;
m.x = 5;
m.f();
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense, I didn't think about this, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

without any context, you can do this

```
foo.f = [x=foo.x]() {
   std::cout << x;
};
```

Comment: @Riptide: Note that this makes a *copy* of the current value of `x` rather than always printing the value of the class member.

Comment: yes, if x is not a int, like class, capture by reference is more reasonable. foo.f = [&x=foo.x]() { ... };